# URL Rewrite to redirect a old host to a new host

Tags: url-rewriting

I know nothing about Url Rewrites, but we have recently changed domain names from `oldcompanyname.co.uk` to `newcompanyname.co.uk`.

We have been told that to get `oldcompanyname.co.uk` to not show up in search results anymore, we need to redirect the old url to the new one.

I have installed `ISAPI_Rewrite 3` but have not been successful in getting the re-direction to work.

On our development servers I've tried the following code without success to redirect any request to `http://tm-devtest2/tmintranet` to `http://tm-devtest2/tmintranet`.

```
# Helicon ISAPI_Rewrite configuration file
# Version 3.1.0.94

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*internet*$
RewriteRule ^$ http://tm-devtest2/tmintranet/ [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !newcompanyname.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newcompanyname.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The RewriteCond is only needed in case the same instance will serve both domains.
L means "Last", i.e. stop rewriting
NC means "no case"
R means Redirect
301 means "Permanently Moved"